# eliminate overlapping of nodes in vis network which consists of 8 undertrees

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm dealing with a case in which the nodes are not connected enough to let vis place them correctly without overlapping.

As mentioned in the title the network consists of 8 undertress.

I attached two pictures for better understanding.

[with physics off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKdgs.jpg)

[with physics on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsF4M.jpg)

I read about clusters but don't know if this feature would solve the problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please describe the desired result and problems you have in each case. As currently written, it's hard to say what exactly are you asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution for me:

I connected the nodes of the subtrees with the most relations (incoming and outgoing edges) with each other.

Then I turned physics on and turned it of after the scene has "settled".

```
network.on("stabilizationIterationsDone", function () {
    network.setOptions( { physics: false } );
    console.log(network.getSeed());
});
```

I refreshed the scene a few times and took the desired seed as randomSeed in the layout option.

I got the hint of using physics from Denis M.s blogpost:
[link to the blogpost](http://gentlelogic.blogspot.com/2015/09/drawing-graphs-with-visjs.html)